# How to pass a random User/Pass (for Basic Authentication) with JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, basic-authentication

I'm using **JMeter** to stress test an API. I've got `Basic Authentication` set up - seems to be working great.

Now, i'm trying to **randomize the credentials** that JMeter passes across the wire. So, there's two ways I know I can do this.

1. Add a custom `HTTP Header` (via an `HTTP Header Manager Element`) and set then value to the random fields (ie. something I've read in from a csv file)
2. Use the `HTTP Authorization Manager Element` and pass in the username and password there.

Now, if I try and use method (1) above, I need to create the following header/data :-

```
Authorization: Basic <some Base64 encoded string in the format username:password>

eg.
Authorization: Basic OnVzZXIxOnBhc3Mx
```

Kewl. simple. BUT that header value is not getting passed across the wire :( I can add any other header type and it's passed across the wire..

hmm .. ok then .. lets try method (2).

Now that works .. but I can only *hardcode* in the username & password. I can't see how I can pass in a username *VARIABLE* (ie. `${usernmae}` ) or a password *VARIABLE* (ie. `${password}` ).... If it's hardcoded, then the server correctly replies with the correct page/data.

so .. can someone please help?

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend trying the following:

1. Create a HTTP Authorization Manager Element
2. Setup the username and password to be variables, ${username} , ${password}
3. Create a CSV file with your usernames and passwords (do not use a header row)
4. create a CSV Data Set Config Element, with the variable names set to "username,password" (no quotes, and no space after the comma)
5. Each thread/loop will read a different value from the CSV file.

Alternately, if you want the value to be truely random for the login, there are some functions you can use to generate random numbers or send in the time of execution.

Comment: Note also that for Basic Auth. you should not put anything in domain column of HTTP Auth. Manager element. Otherwise you get it inside Base64 encoded value of the Authorization header.

Comment: and make sure Protocol [http] field is empty in HTTP Request